# Not getting result with find command in custom alias in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, find

I have this command in my .bashrc

```
 mygrep() {
         find /var/www/site1 -exec grep -Hn "$1" {} \;
     }
```

But sometimes its not returing results

But this command return full results

```
grep -r "serch term" /var/www/site1
```

whats wrong with above function

Comment: I don't see any difference. Why not add -type f into your find? Is your grep aliased?

Comment: no , grep is not aliased. i will try -type f

Comment: i find that if i use normal grep then it search for pattern even inside the string like it will slect   `master` if i search for `ast` but my custom find command only find `master` not `ast` as match

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your function when run on my Linux box. To make results look absolutely the same, add the `-n` option to both grep calls: `grep -rn "serch term" /var/www/site1`.

This is what I did to compare the output of both commands on the fly (in bash):

`diff <(grep -rn ast /var/www/site1) <(mygrep ast)`

Comment: I have tried that but still there are many keywords which dont come in mygrep but coming in grep. I have many subdirectories in that folder. is that be the reason. may be find is not going in those directroies. how can i debug

Comment: Re-running my test on a more complex tree of directories still showed no difference. Are you using the GNU implementations of find and grep? My `find` is from GNU findutils 4.4.2, and my `grep` is GNU grep 2.9. Other implementations of find and grep are likely to behave differently in certain cases.